# React Styled-components is not applying styled to child elements

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to apply this media Queries to the child element but the child element can not be modified as it is used in another components, so, I want to "inherit" those styles to the Child element but it is not working like this

Do you know why?

```js
export const StyledFather = styled(Father)`
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .customer_column{
      display: none;
    }
    .orderNumber_column{
      display: none;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .tag_column{
      display: none;
    }
  }
`;

const Father = () => (
  <UnstyledFather >
    <Child />
  </UnstyledFather>
);


class Child extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <UnstyledChild />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve the problem. The clasName attribute needed to be passed via props to the child element:

```js
const Father = () => (
  <UnstyledFather >
    <Child className/> //pass the className attr
  </UnstyledFather>
);

class Child extends PureComponent {
  const { className } = this.props //received via props
  render() {
    return (
      <UnstyledChild />
    )
  }
}

Child.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
};
```

And that's it!